# Generating group permutations: an extended Heap's algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, combinatorics

Suppose we have a sequence of sequences `<1, 2> <3, 4>`. There, we have two groups: `<1, 2>` and `<3, 4>`. The idea is to permute `<1, 2>`, and for each such permutation permute the `<3, 4>`. So all possible permutations are:

1. `<1, 2> <3, 4>`
2. `<1, 2> <4, 3>`
3. `<2, 1> <3, 4>`
4. `<2, 1> <4, 3>`

Also, my algorithm can handle both `null` elements (which are considered to be smaller than any non-null element by the comparator), and `null` or empty groups.

Actually, what you are about to see is an extended [Heap's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm).

(The entire repository is at [GitHub](https://github.com/coderodde/MultipleGroupPermuter.java).)

### Code

**`com.github.coderodde.util.combinatorics.MultipleGroupPermuter.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util.combinatorics;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 * This class provides a method for generating permutations over groups of 
 * elements. If the groups are {@code <1, 2>, null, <3, 4>, <5>}, the all 
 * permutations produced by the method {@link computeGroupPermutations} are:
 * <ul>
 *  <li>{@code [1, 2] null [3, 4] [5]}</li>
 *  <li>{@code [1, 2] null [4, 3] [5]}</li>
 *  <li>{@code [2, 1] null [3, 4] [5]}</li>
 *  <li>{@code [2, 1] null [4, 3] [5]}</li>
 * </ul>.
 * <p>
 * Unfortunately, this permuter cannot "collapse" equal group permutation in
 * case some groups have equal elements. For example, {@code <null, 1, null>}
 * won't produce 
 * <ul>
 *  <li>{@code [1, null, null]}</li>
 *  <li>{@code [null, 1, null]}</li>
 *  <li>{@code [null, null, 1]},</li>
 * </ul>
 * but instead
 * <ol>
 *  <li>{@code [1, null, null]}</li>
 *  <li>{@code [1, null, null]}</li>
 *  <li>{@code [null, 1, null]}</li>
 *  <li>{@code [null, 1, null]}</li>
 *  <li>{@code [null, null, 1]}</li>
 *  <li>{@code [null, null, 1]}.</li>
 * </ol>
 * There is, however, a simple technique to mitigate the above issue: put all 
 * the group permutations into a {@link HashSet}, and then call 
 * {@code toArray()} on the hash set in order to obtain the unique group 
 * permutations.
 * 
 * @param <T> the type of the group element.
 */
public final class MultipleGroupPermuter<T> {

    // The actual group list. Will be modified by the computeGroupPermutations 
    // method.
    private final List<List<T>> data;
    private final List<List<List<T>>> result;
    
    /**
     * Constructs this object with a given group list.
     * 
     * @param groupList the list of groups.
     */
    public MultipleGroupPermuter(List<List<T>> groupList) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(groupList, "The input group list is null.");
        this.data = groupList;
        this.result = new ArrayList<>(getNumberOfResultPermutations());
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the list holding all the group permutations. The algorithm under
     * the hood is an extended 
     * <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap%27s_algorithm">
     * Heap's algorithm</a>.
     * 
     * @return the list of all the group permutations.
     */
    public List<List<List<T>>> computeGroupPermutations() {
        Objects.requireNonNull(data, "The input data is null.");
        
        if (data.isEmpty()) {
            return new ArrayList<>(1);
        }
        
        computeGroupPermutationsImpl(getGroupSize(data.get(0)), 0);
        return result;
    }
    
    private void computeGroupPermutationsImpl(int n, int listIndex) {
        if (listIndex == data.size() - 1) {
            if (n == 1 || n == 0) {
                result.add(deepCopyGroupPermutation());
                return;
            }
            
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                    computeGroupPermutationsImpl(n - 1, listIndex);
                    Collections.swap(data.get(listIndex), i, n - 1);
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                    computeGroupPermutationsImpl(n - 1, listIndex);
                    Collections.swap(data.get(listIndex), 0, n - 1);
                }
            }
            
            computeGroupPermutationsImpl(n - 1, listIndex);
        } else {
            // Here, listIndex < data.size() - 1:
            if (n == 1 || n == 0) {
                computeGroupPermutationsImpl(
                        getGroupSize(data.get(listIndex + 1)), 
                        listIndex + 1);
                return;
            }
            
            if (n % 2 == 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                    computeGroupPermutationsImpl(n - 1, listIndex);
                    Collections.swap(data.get(listIndex), i, n - 1);
                }
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
                    computeGroupPermutationsImpl(n - 1, listIndex);
                    Collections.swap(data.get(listIndex), 0, n - 1);
                }
            }
            
            computeGroupPermutationsImpl(n - 1, listIndex);
        }
    }
    
    private List<List<T>> deepCopyGroupPermutation() {
        List<List<T>> copy = new ArrayList<>(data.size());
        
        for (List<T> group : data) {
            if (group == null) {
                copy.add(null);
            } else {
                copy.add(new ArrayList<>(group));
            }
        }
        
        return copy;
    }
    
    private int getNumberOfResultPermutations() {
        int numberOfPermutations = 1;
        
        for (List<T> group : data) {
            numberOfPermutations *= factorial(getGroupSize(group));
            
            if (numberOfPermutations <= 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "The current invocation would yell too many group " + 
                                "permutations.");
            }
        }
        
        return numberOfPermutations;
    }
    
    private static int factorial(int n) {
        switch (n) {
            case 0:
            case 1:
                return 1;
                
            default:
                return n * factorial(n - 1);
        }
    }
    
    private static <T> int getGroupSize(List<T> list) {
        if (list == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        
        return list.size();
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.combinatorics.MultipleGroupPermuterDemo.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util.combinatorics;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

public final class MultipleGroupPermuterDemo {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<List<Integer>> data = new ArrayList<>();
        
        data.add(null);
        data.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
        data.add(Arrays.asList(4));
        data.add(Arrays.asList());
        data.add(Arrays.asList(null, 6, 7, 5));
        data.add(Arrays.asList());
        data.add(null);
        
        // Make sure 'data' remains intact since the permuter modifies the order
        // of elements in the input data:
        List<List<Integer>> dataCopy = copyData(data);
        
        // Compute all the group permutations:
        List<List<List<Integer>>> groupPemutationList = 
                new MultipleGroupPermuter<>(dataCopy)
                        .computeGroupPermutations();
        
        // Put all the group permutations into lexicographic order:
        sort(groupPemutationList);
        
        // Print all the group permutations in lexicographic order:
        System.out.println(
                convertGroupPemutationsToString(groupPemutationList));
        
        // Build the map mapping each unique group permutations to its 
        // multiplicity:
        Map<List<List<Integer>>, Integer> frequencyMap = 
                new HashMap<>(groupPemutationList.size());
        
        for (List<List<Integer>> groupPermutation : groupPemutationList) {
            frequencyMap.put(groupPermutation, 
                             frequencyMap.getOrDefault(
                                     groupPermutation, 
                                     0) + 1);
        }
        
        System.out.println(
                "Distinct group permutations: " + frequencyMap.size());
        
        System.out.println(
                "Total group permutations: " 
                        + countAllPermutations(frequencyMap));
    }
    
    /**
     * Counts the total number of group permutations stored in the 
     * {@code frequencyMap}.
     * 
     * @param <T>          the element type of groups.
     * @param frequencyMap the map mapping each unique group permutation to its
     *                     multiplicity.
     * 
     * @return the total number of group permutations.
     */
    private static <T> int 
        countAllPermutations(Map<List<List<T>>, Integer> frequencyMap) {
            
        int numberOfAllPermutations = 0;
        
        for (Integer count : frequencyMap.values()) {
            numberOfAllPermutations += count;
        }
        
        return numberOfAllPermutations;
    }
        
    /**
     * Computes the string representing the input group permutations.
     * 
     * @param <T>                  the element type of groups.
     * @param groupPermutationList the list of group permutations.
     * @return                     the string describing all the group 
     *                             permutations.
     */   
    private static <T> String 
        convertGroupPemutationsToString(
                List<List<List<T>>> groupPermutationList) {
            
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        int numberOfGroupPemutations = groupPermutationList.size();
        int maximumLineNumberWidth = 
                Integer.toString(numberOfGroupPemutations).length();
        
        String format = "%" + maximumLineNumberWidth + "d: %s";
        int lineNumber = 1;
        
        for (List<List<T>> groupPermutation : groupPermutationList) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append('\n');
            }
            
            String groupPemutationString = 
                    convertGroupPemutationToString(groupPermutation);
            
            stringBuilder.append(
                    String.format(
                            format,
                            lineNumber++, 
                            groupPemutationString));
        }
        
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
        
    /**
     * Returns the string representing the input of a single group permutation.
     * 
     * @param <T>             the element type of groups.
     * @param groupPemutation the input group permutation.
     * @return                the string representing the input group.
     */
    private static <T> String 
        convertGroupPemutationToString(List<List<T>> groupPemutation) {
            
       StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
       boolean first = true;
       
       for (List<T> group : groupPemutation) {
           if (first) {
               first = false;
           } else {
               stringBuilder.append(' ');
           }
           
           stringBuilder.append(Objects.toString(group));
       }
       
       return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
        
    /**
     * Returns the deep copy of {@code data}. We need this in order to keep the
     * actual data for the permuter intact.
     * 
     * @param <T>  the element type of groups.
     * @param data the data to deep copy.
     * @return     the deep copy of the input data.
     */     
    private static <T> List<List<T>> copyData(List<List<T>> data) {
        List<List<T>> deepCopy = new ArrayList<>(data.size());
        
        for (List<T> list : data) {
            if (list == null) {
                deepCopy.add(null);
            } else {
                deepCopy.add(new ArrayList<>(list));
            }
        }
        
        return deepCopy;
    }
    
    /**
     * Sorts the input group permutation list into lexicographic order. Note
     * that this sort routine deems {@code null} values less than any other
     * non-null integer.
     * 
     * @param groupPermutationList the list of all the group permutations.
     */
    private static void sort(List<List<List<Integer>>> groupPermutationList) {
        
        GroupComparator<Integer> groupComparator = 
                new GroupComparator<>(Integer::compareTo);
        
        GroupPermutationComparator<Integer> groupPermutationComparator = 
                new GroupPermutationComparator<>(groupComparator);
        
        Collections.sort(groupPermutationList, groupPermutationComparator);
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.combinatorics.GroupComparator.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util.combinatorics;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This class implements a comparator for comparing the groups. Note that it 
 * won't accept groups of different sizes and will throw an
 * {@link IllegalArgumentException}.
 * 
 * @param <T> the element type of a group.
 */
public final class GroupComparator<T> implements Comparator<List<T>> {

    private final Comparator<T> elementComparator;
    
    public GroupComparator(Comparator<T> elementComparator) {
        this.elementComparator = elementComparator;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compare(List<T> group1, List<T> group2) {
        if (group1 == null) {
            if (group2 == null) {
                // Both null:
                return 0;
            } else {
                // group1 null and group2 is non null:
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            // Here, group1 != null:
            if (group2 == null) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        
        // Here, both group1 and group2 are not null:
        if (group1.size() != group2.size()) {
            // Size mismatch, throw:
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The input groups are of differnt sizes. "
                            + group1.size() 
                            + " vs. " 
                            + group2.size());
        }
        
        // Here, group1 != null and group2 != null and both of the same size:
        for (int i = 0; i < group1.size(); i++) {
            T element1 = group1.get(i);
            T element2 = group2.get(i);
            
            if (element1 == null) {
                if (element2 == null) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            } else {
                // Here, element1 != null:
                if (element2 == null) {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            
            int cmp = elementComparator.compare(element1, element2);
            
            if (cmp != 0) {
                // Found a different spot, return:
                return cmp;
            }
        }
        
        // Here, both group1 and group2 are the same:
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**`com.github.coderodde.util.combinatorics.GroupPermutationComparator.java:`**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util.combinatorics;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * This class implements a comparator comparing group permutations It accepts 
 * only group permutations of the same size. If the aforementioned invariant is
 * broken, this comparator throws {@link IllegalArgumentException}.
 * 
 * @param <T> the element type of groups. 
 */
public final class GroupPermutationComparator<T> 
        implements Comparator<List<List<T>>> {
    
    private final Comparator<List<T>> groupComparator;
    
    public GroupPermutationComparator(Comparator<List<T>> groupComparator) {
        this.groupComparator = groupComparator;
    }
    
    @Override
    public int compare(List<List<T>> groupPermutation1,
                       List<List<T>> groupPermutation2) {
        if (groupPermutation1.size() != groupPermutation2.size()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "The input group permutations are of different size. " 
                            + groupPermutation1.size()
                            + " vs. "
                            + groupPermutation2.size());
        }
        
        for (int i = 0; i < groupPermutation1.size(); i++) {
            List<T> group1 = groupPermutation1.get(i);
            List<T> group2 = groupPermutation2.get(i);
            
            int cmp = groupComparator.compare(group1, group2);
            
            if (cmp != 0) {
                return cmp;
            }
        }
        
        return 0;
    }
}
```

### Demo output

The demo program prints:

```
  1: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [null, 6, 7, 5] [] null
  2: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [null, 7, 6, 5] [] null
  3: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [null, 5, 6, 7] [] null
  4: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [null, 6, 5, 7] [] null
  5: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [null, 7, 5, 6] [] null
  6: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [null, 5, 7, 6] [] null
  7: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [5, null, 6, 7] [] null
  8: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [5, null, 7, 6] [] null
  9: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [5, 6, null, 7] [] null
 10: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [5, 6, 7, null] [] null
 11: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [5, 7, null, 6] [] null
 12: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [5, 7, 6, null] [] null
 13: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [6, null, 7, 5] [] null
 14: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [6, null, 5, 7] [] null
 15: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [6, 5, null, 7] [] null
 16: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [6, 5, 7, null] [] null
 17: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [6, 7, null, 5] [] null
 18: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [6, 7, 5, null] [] null
 19: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [7, null, 6, 5] [] null
 20: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [7, null, 5, 6] [] null
 21: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [7, 5, null, 6] [] null
 22: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [7, 5, 6, null] [] null
 23: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [7, 6, null, 5] [] null
 24: null [1, 2, 3] [4] [] [7, 6, 5, null] [] null
 25: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [null, 5, 6, 7] [] null
 26: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [null, 6, 5, 7] [] null
 27: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [null, 7, 5, 6] [] null
 28: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [null, 5, 7, 6] [] null
 29: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [null, 7, 6, 5] [] null
 30: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [null, 6, 7, 5] [] null
 31: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [5, null, 6, 7] [] null
 32: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [5, null, 7, 6] [] null
 33: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [5, 6, null, 7] [] null
 34: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [5, 6, 7, null] [] null
 35: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [5, 7, null, 6] [] null
 36: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [5, 7, 6, null] [] null
 37: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [6, null, 5, 7] [] null
 38: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [6, null, 7, 5] [] null
 39: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [6, 5, null, 7] [] null
 40: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [6, 5, 7, null] [] null
 41: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [6, 7, null, 5] [] null
 42: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [6, 7, 5, null] [] null
 43: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [7, null, 5, 6] [] null
 44: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [7, null, 6, 5] [] null
 45: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [7, 5, null, 6] [] null
 46: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [7, 5, 6, null] [] null
 47: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [7, 6, null, 5] [] null
 48: null [1, 3, 2] [4] [] [7, 6, 5, null] [] null
 49: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [null, 7, 6, 5] [] null
 50: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [null, 6, 7, 5] [] null
 51: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [null, 6, 5, 7] [] null
 52: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [null, 5, 6, 7] [] null
 53: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [null, 5, 7, 6] [] null
 54: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [null, 7, 5, 6] [] null
 55: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [5, null, 6, 7] [] null
 56: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [5, null, 7, 6] [] null
 57: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [5, 6, null, 7] [] null
 58: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [5, 6, 7, null] [] null
 59: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [5, 7, null, 6] [] null
 60: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [5, 7, 6, null] [] null
 61: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [6, null, 7, 5] [] null
 62: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [6, null, 5, 7] [] null
 63: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [6, 5, null, 7] [] null
 64: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [6, 5, 7, null] [] null
 65: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [6, 7, null, 5] [] null
 66: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [6, 7, 5, null] [] null
 67: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [7, null, 6, 5] [] null
 68: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [7, null, 5, 6] [] null
 69: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [7, 5, null, 6] [] null
 70: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [7, 5, 6, null] [] null
 71: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [7, 6, null, 5] [] null
 72: null [2, 1, 3] [4] [] [7, 6, 5, null] [] null
 73: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [null, 6, 7, 5] [] null
 74: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [null, 7, 6, 5] [] null
 75: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [null, 5, 6, 7] [] null
 76: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [null, 6, 5, 7] [] null
 77: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [null, 7, 5, 6] [] null
 78: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [null, 5, 7, 6] [] null
 79: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [5, null, 6, 7] [] null
 80: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [5, null, 7, 6] [] null
 81: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [5, 6, null, 7] [] null
 82: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [5, 6, 7, null] [] null
 83: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [5, 7, null, 6] [] null
 84: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [5, 7, 6, null] [] null
 85: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [6, null, 7, 5] [] null
 86: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [6, null, 5, 7] [] null
 87: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [6, 5, null, 7] [] null
 88: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [6, 5, 7, null] [] null
 89: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [6, 7, null, 5] [] null
 90: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [6, 7, 5, null] [] null
 91: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [7, null, 6, 5] [] null
 92: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [7, null, 5, 6] [] null
 93: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [7, 5, null, 6] [] null
 94: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [7, 5, 6, null] [] null
 95: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [7, 6, null, 5] [] null
 96: null [2, 3, 1] [4] [] [7, 6, 5, null] [] null
 97: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [null, 7, 5, 6] [] null
 98: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [null, 5, 7, 6] [] null
 99: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [null, 7, 6, 5] [] null
100: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [null, 6, 7, 5] [] null
101: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [null, 6, 5, 7] [] null
102: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [null, 5, 6, 7] [] null
103: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [5, null, 7, 6] [] null
104: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [5, null, 6, 7] [] null
105: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [5, 6, null, 7] [] null
106: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [5, 6, 7, null] [] null
107: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [5, 7, null, 6] [] null
108: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [5, 7, 6, null] [] null
109: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [6, null, 7, 5] [] null
110: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [6, null, 5, 7] [] null
111: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [6, 5, null, 7] [] null
112: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [6, 5, 7, null] [] null
113: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [6, 7, null, 5] [] null
114: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [6, 7, 5, null] [] null
115: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [7, null, 5, 6] [] null
116: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [7, null, 6, 5] [] null
117: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [7, 5, null, 6] [] null
118: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [7, 5, 6, null] [] null
119: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [7, 6, null, 5] [] null
120: null [3, 1, 2] [4] [] [7, 6, 5, null] [] null
121: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [null, 7, 6, 5] [] null
122: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [null, 6, 7, 5] [] null
123: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [null, 6, 5, 7] [] null
124: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [null, 5, 6, 7] [] null
125: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [null, 5, 7, 6] [] null
126: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [null, 7, 5, 6] [] null
127: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [5, null, 6, 7] [] null
128: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [5, null, 7, 6] [] null
129: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [5, 6, null, 7] [] null
130: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [5, 6, 7, null] [] null
131: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [5, 7, null, 6] [] null
132: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [5, 7, 6, null] [] null
133: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [6, null, 7, 5] [] null
134: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [6, null, 5, 7] [] null
135: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [6, 5, null, 7] [] null
136: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [6, 5, 7, null] [] null
137: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [6, 7, null, 5] [] null
138: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [6, 7, 5, null] [] null
139: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [7, null, 6, 5] [] null
140: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [7, null, 5, 6] [] null
141: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [7, 5, null, 6] [] null
142: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [7, 5, 6, null] [] null
143: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [7, 6, null, 5] [] null
144: null [3, 2, 1] [4] [] [7, 6, 5, null] [] null
Distinct group permutations: 144
Total group permutations: 144
```

### Critique request

As always, I would to hear anything that comes to mind.

Comment: We've been over [avoiding string concatenation during print](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/288608/25834), but it seems like that feedback isn't taking hold.

Comment: @Reinderien Point.